# Type H <return> for immediate help does not work

Tags: errors, compilation-error

I've never been able to figure out why this doesn't work.
I recently tried to add the color package to use some different colors in my pdf output.
I now get the following error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.122
```

If I type H  I just get a history of previous commands in Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\tomas\OneDrive\Dokument\_markdown\stats\script> H

  Id CommandLine
  -- -----------
   1 CD "C:\Users\tomas\OneDrive\Dokument\_markdown\stats\script"
   2 .\_RUN.ps1
   3 .\_RUN.ps1
   4 .\_RUN.ps1
   5 .\_RUN.ps1
   6 .\_RUN.ps1
   7 .\_RUN.ps1
   8 .\_RUN.ps1
   9 .\_RUN.ps1
  10 .\_RUN.ps1
  11 .\_RUN.ps1
  12 .\_RUN.ps1
  13 .\_RUN.ps1
  14 cls
  15 cls
```

FYI: _RUN.ps1 is a script that executes pandoc. Pandoc converts a .md file to .pdf in this case.

Also, its hard to understand wich line is number 122 since I have more than one document as input (1 md file, on header.tex file and 1 .yaml).

**Question:** Any advice on how to troubleshoot further?
(Note that I'm not asking how to solve this particular problem, but how to troubleshoot errors like these in general, as they are quite common to get)

Comment: well try in powershell to compile your tex file directly: e.g. with `pdflatex yourfile` then it will work. Then you will have to figure out what your script is doing, but imho that it is not a tex question.

Comment: if tex has not stopped at the terminal waiting for input witha `?` prompt there is nowhere to type `h`. You do not show any `?` in your fragment, ar you just showing the log of a completed run?  You appear to be typing H to your commandline interpreter (where it probably means hisory)

Answer (score 1):

If you run tex in the default error stop mode, after an error it stops with a `?` prompt to which you can type `?` for help or `x` to quit and spme other responses.

It appears that your script has run tex in batchmode (or scrollmode) where it does not stop after an error it prints that mesaage but does not stop for user input it just tries to recover.

So you are seeing the log of an already completed latex run, then typing `h` to the powershell commandline where it is an alias for get-history:

```
> help h

NAME
    Get-History

SYNTAX
    Get-History [[-Id] <long[]>] [[-Count] <int>]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    ghy
    h
    history


REMARKS
    Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
        -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
        -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help Get-History -Online" or
           go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113317.
```

Comment: This is most likely it. I will see what I can do. Thanks!